# how to make md-sidenav responsive in material 2

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material2

I am using this code to make toolbar responsive

```
<md-toolbar>
  <div fxLayout fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-xs>
    <button md-raised-button><md-icon>add</md-icon>New Role</button>
    <span style=" flex-grow: 0.1"></span>

    <button md-raised-button><md-icon>mode_edit</md-icon></button>
    <button md-raised-button><md-icon>delete</md-icon></button>

    <span style=" flex-grow: 2"></span>
    <button md-raised-button><md-icon>perm_identity</md-icon>Add User</button>

    <span style=" flex-grow: 0.1"></span>
    <button md-raised-button><md-icon>delete</md-icon></button>
  </div>


  <!--button that will be visible when screen is small-->
  <span style="flex: 1 1 auto;"></span>
  <button md-button [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu" fxHide="false" fxHide.gt-xs>
     <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
  </button>
</md-toolbar>
```

Now when the screen size is extra small all other button gets hidden and a menu button is shown. The problem I am facing is that when the screen is of full size the `flex-grow` properties are not working in the toolbar. I have given the flex-grow to 0.1,2 in span element, but on UI there is no gap between button.

[image]

What could be the possible issue?

And is there any other better way to make toolbar responsive?

**Updated**

I have tried `fxFlex` directive still no effect. 
As all the buttons are under div, now if I remove that div container, it works. But as I have to hide all the buttons based on screen size so div is necessary to  contain all the buttons.

Comment: if you want a gap, use `fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="10px"`

Comment: this will give the equal gap between all the items and I dont want that

Comment: Well, maybe you should have given this precision don't you think ? Anyway, you use the material layout library, so use the documentation and discover things like `fxFlex="1 0.1 auto"` that will help you a lot.

Comment: Thank you, could you also post a picture of the problem if you can ?

Comment: Added the image

Comment: Please try `fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148469/discussion-between-sunil-garg-and-trichetriche).